Pointwise Limit of Riemannian Isometries is a Riemannian Isometry
In Lee's Introduction to Riemannian Manifolds, problem 6-8 asks the reader to show that the pointwise limit $\phi : M \to \widetilde M$ of a sequence of Riemannian isometries $\phi_i : M \to \widetilde M$ is also a Riemannian isometry, where $M$ and $\widetilde M$ are connected though not necessarily complete. I first want to show that $\phi$ is a local isometry, which will follow if I can show that it is both smooth and preserves metrics. But aside from the fact that pointwise limits need not even be continuous, there's no reason to expect that pullbacks/differentials play nice with pointwise limits either so directly demonstrating preservation of metrics seems fraught. Instead, I used commutativity of continuous functions with limits to show that $\phi$ preserves distances (which, as a bonus, also proves injectivity of $\phi$):
\begin{align}
d_{\widetilde g}(\phi(p), \phi(q)) &= d_{\widetilde g}(\lim \phi_i(p), \lim \phi_i(q)) \\\\
&= \lim d_{\widetilde{g}}(\phi_i(p), \phi_i(q)) \\\\
&= \lim d_g(p, q) \\\\
&= d_g(p, q).
\end{align}
Now I only need $\phi$ to be continuous, and I should be able to apply Myers-Steenrod (proved in problem 6-7). How can I show that the pointwise limit of isometries is continuous? Or is there perhaps a better way to prove $\phi$ is a local isometry?
Update: Thanks to Moishe Kohan's comment, I was able to reacquaint  myself with Ascoli's Theorem and use it to prove continuity of $\phi$. I am, however, still puzzled by the following.
As a further question: The hint implies that the reader should show surjectivity of $\phi$ using a convergent sequence of points in $TM$, but I've seemingly demonstrated it using only the fact that $\phi$ is a local isometry. This is of course fishy because that would imply that all local isometries are automatically global isometries. My "proof":
Choose a limit point $y$ of $\phi(M)$ with a uniformly normal neighborhood $U$. We should be able to assume $U$ is sufficiently small that there is at least one $\phi(x) \in U$ whose injectivity radius inj($\phi(x)$) is large enough that $U \subseteq B_{\mathrm{inj}(\phi(x))}(\phi(x))$. That is, $\exp_{\phi(x)}$ should be diffeomorphic on all of $U$.
Set $w = \exp_{\phi(x)}^{-1}(y) \in T_{\phi(x)} \widetilde{M}$ and $v = d\phi_x^{-1}(w) \in T_x M$. (Since $\phi$ is a local diffeomorphism, its differential is an isomorphism at every point.) Then, by naturality of the exponential map,
$$
y = \exp_{\phi(x)}(w) = \exp_{\phi(x)}(d\phi_x(v)) = \phi(\exp_x(v)).
$$
Why is this wrong?

Are you aware of the Arzela-Ascoli theorem?

Ah, reviewing Munkres, it appears I used to be! But I unfortunately haven't had to think about the topology of function spaces in quite a number of years. However, I've now been able to prove continuity of $\phi$, so thank you! Hopefully someone can just as adroitly hint at the problem in my surjectivity proof!

Local isometries of complete equidimensional connected Riemannian manifolds are surjective. This is false for incomplete manifolds.
